# Logic error while trying to scan txt file for specific word

Tags: java

I have a txt file that contains this:

```
Mary had a little lamb little lamb
little lamb. Mary had a little lamb.
That's all? Did the lamb follow Mary
wherever Mary went?
```

I'm trying to write some code that scans the txt file for the word 'Mary', counts how many times it appears, and then prints that number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner("test.txt");

        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextToken = reader.next();
            if (nextToken.equals("Mary"))
                count++;
        }

        System.out.println("The word 'Mary' was found on " + count + " lines.");
    }


}
```

While the code compiles, I keep getting incorrect input, with the system printing `"The word 'Mary' was found on 0 lines."`

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: `contains()` instead of `equals()`

Answer (score 4):

You aren't actually reading from a file.

You need to declare the scanner as `new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));` Otherwise, the scanner is literally scanning the string "test.txt" for Mary.

See the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) doc for the different constructors

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've tried making that amendment but the system throws a "unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared thrown" error :/

Comment: @user2893128 you can give the full path to the text file (ie "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.txt") or you can move the text file into the same location as your Test.class file

Comment: @RyanCarlson I think so - both my test.java and test.txt files are in my desktop

Comment: @user2893128 is your Test.class file also on your desktop?

Comment: @vandale Yes, I've tried specifying the full path but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @user2893128 What program are you using to compile/run your program?

Comment: @user2893128 Double-check the file name and location for typos, including uppercase/lowercase errors.

Answer (score 0):

vandale is correct in that `new Scanner("test.txt")` should be `new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))`.

However, if you want to find the number of lines in which there is the word "Mary", you'll need to change your code a bit.  Look at the lines with comments:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] blargs) {
        int count = 0;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextToken = reader.nextLine(); // nextLine() instead of next().
            if (nextToken.contains("Mary")) // contains() instead of equals()
                count++;
        }
        System.out.println("The word 'Mary' was found on " + count + " lines.");
    }
}
```